# Find the volume of the surface.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, solid-geometry

Find the volume of the solid in $xyz$-plane bounded by $y=x^2,y=2-x^2,z=0$ and $z=y+3$.

I have found the answer $\frac {13 \pi} {6}$. Is it correct at all? Please verify it.

Thank you very much.

I have drawn it in my mind. Can anybody help me plotting it online? How do I draw it to make sure that I have judged the correct surface intuitionally?

**EDIT** $:$ I have found it in the following way $:$

The required volume is

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{x^2} ^{2-x^2} \int_{0}^{3+y}\ \mathrm {dz\ dy\ dx}$$ i.e. the volume of the required solid is $$16 \int_{0}^{1} (1-x^2)\ \mathrm {dx}$$ which simplifies to $\frac {32} {3}$.

Now please verify my solution now.

Comment: We'll be happy to verify your work in obtaining that answer.  Answers can be found in solutions to exercises, whereas one's work in getting an answer is not.  Please show us your work, the integral you set up, its bounds, your integration, and your evaluation to arrive at the answer you posted.  Then we can verify your answer, or correct it.

Comment: $$\int_0^1 16\sqrt x\cdot dx = \color{red}{\frac{32}3}\neq\frac{13\pi}6$$

Comment: Try using https://www.geogebra.org/3d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set up the integral like this:

$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{x^2}^{2-x^2}\int_0^{y+3} \ dz\ dy\ dx$

As for the figure, you have a cylinder with a cross section of two parabola. Cut at one end at an angle.

The area of the cross section is:

$\int_{-1}^{1} 2 - 2x^2 = \frac 83$

Does slicing at an angle make a difference?  The cross section is symmetric about the line $y = 1.$  As much is cut off below the this line as above it.

$\int_0^4\int_{-1}^{1} 2 - 2x^2 \ dx \ dz = \frac {32}{3}$

Comment: I have done it in exactly the same fashion @Doug M.